# TailwindCSS DarkMode styles not applied to elements when toggling 'dark' class to HTML tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, tailwind-ui

I'm encountering an issue with implementing dark mode styles in my web application. I've followed the recommended approach of using Tailwind CSS's built-in dark mode support by adding the 'dark' class to the HTML tree, but for some reason, the dark mode styles are not being applied.

Specifically, I'm trying to get 'dark:bg-bgDark' to be applied when darkMode is toggled. Currently, the background stays constant to bg-bgLight.

My tailwind.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    darkMode: 'selector',
    extend: {
      boxShadow: {
        'custom': '0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)'
      },
    },
    screens: {
      'sm': {'max': '550px'},
    },
    colors: {
      bgLight: 'hsl(0, 0%, 98%)',
      textColor: 'hsl(200, 15%, 8%)',
      bgDark: 'hsl(207, 26%, 17%)'
    },
    fontSize: {
      'sm': ['0.875rem', { lineHeight: '1.25rem' }], 
      'md': ['1.2rem', { lineHeight: '1.75rem' }],
      'big': '28px'
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

My HomePage.jsx:

```
import { Header, CountryCard } from "../components";
import { SearchBar, Filter } from '../utils'
import countries from "../assets/data.json";
import useTheme from '../hooks/useTheme'

const HomePage = () => {
  const [toggleTheme, theme] = useTheme()
  return (
    <div className="bg-bgLight dark:bg-bgDark">
      <Header theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
      <div className="flex m-10 justify-between">
        <SearchBar />
        <Filter countries={countries} />
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
        {countries.map((country) => (
          <CountryCard key={country.alpha3Code} country={country} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

useTheme.jsx:

```
import { Header, CountryCard } from "../components";
import { SearchBar, Filter } from '../utils'
import countries from "../assets/data.json";
import useTheme from '../hooks/useTheme'

const HomePage = () => {
  const [toggleTheme, theme] = useTheme()
  return (
    <div className="bg-bgLight dark:bg-bgDark">
      <Header theme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
      <div className="flex m-10 justify-between">
        <SearchBar />
        <Filter countries={countries} />
      </div>

      <div className="flex flex-wrap justify-center">
        {countries.map((country) => (
          <CountryCard key={country.alpha3Code} country={country} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

I tried using 'class' instead of 'selector' in the config for darkMode.

I made sure the class 'dark' was being applied and removed accordingly to the HTML element on the DOM when toggling darkMode.

I made sure local storage and state was updating properly.

Comment: It would be great. if you can create a StackBlitz/CodeSandbox URL so that we can quickly resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

For the selector, specify the attribute you are looking for as below

```
darkMode: ['selector', '[data-theme-mode="dark"]'],
```

Should correctly find the selector then and toggle.